# Webelement.isenabled returns True even the element is disabled

Tags: selenium

Selenium Webdriver:
I have an element which is "disabled".
I am trying to get the status of element using Webelement.isenabled to be false and it returns true.
The HTML of the element is as below.

```
<a id="headerCheckInOrderSelectionvalButton" disabled="disabled">Create</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag does not support the `disabled` attribute. The list of supported attributes can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes.

Since the `disabled` attribute is not supported on anchor tags in the HTML spec, Selenium does not support it as well. Since you cannot disable an anchor tag, it makes sense that `IsEnabled` returns true — it is enabled, and you cannot disable it.